# FireFox and IE9 tries to download or show json-response instead of letting javascript parse it

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, cross-browser

**Update**

My problem was that I used event.preventDefault() instead of return false to hinder the form from posting normally. FF and IE didn't like that and broke the JS by that line. I removed that and appended return false at the end and this solved the problem. Thanks to Darin Dimitrov for the extensive checklist.

**Original question**

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 and jquery ajax to post json-data to the server and receive a response. However, when I'm using Chrome it reads the json-response normally, updating the divs that I want etc. With IE and FF it doesn't work though. They read just the response and shows only that on the page.

I saw some other threads mentioning to define the mime type as "text/plain". This changed the previous behavior of prompting the user to download the json-response instead.

This is the javascript for making the post:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: $("#formRegister").attr("action"),
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            alertMessage(data.Message);

        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
```

This is the ActionMethod receiving the call and returning a JsonResponse:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Register(UserRegisterPackage package)
    {
        ClientAlert alert = new ClientAlert();
        if (package.Password != null)
        {       
            //bool success = Removed for simplicity's sake.
            bool success = true;
            if (success)
            {                    
                alert.Message = "Success!";                    
            }
            else
            {                    
                alert.Message = "Failed to register";                    
            }
        }
        else
        {                
            alert.Message = "You need to enter a password!";                
        }
        return Json(alert, "text/plain");
    }
```

As I said, when the content type is defined as text/plain the browser shows only the response and when it's not defined it prompts the user to download the json-response instead.

With FF I seem to get an error about:

```
"event is not defined
event.preventDefault(); "
```

This could have something to do with the error.. but I need to prevent the form from posting normally. Is this done differently in FF or IE?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried defining a different content-type, such as 'text/json'?

Comment: Gives same result as not defining the content-type; browser tries to download the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things to try:

1. If this `$.ajax` call is made inside the `.click` or `.submit` handler of some anchor or `<form>` make sure you `return false;` at the end in order to cancel the default behavior and leave time for your AJAX request to execute. The `attr('action')` that you are using leaves me to believe that this is the case.
2. Remove `traditional: true` parameter, you are sending a JSON request => it is irrelevant.
3. Make sure there aren't some other javascript errors on your page as they might stop js execution and proceed into normal form submission
4. Remove all `text/plain` from your server if you intend to return JSON. It's meaningless to do something like this and it's definitely not where your problem comes from. Simply use `return Json(alert);`.

So if you are AJAXifying a form you don't even need any JSON requests, simply:

```
$('#formRegister').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alertMessage(data.Message);
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

and if you intend to send JSON requests then your code seems fine, jsu make sure there aren't some other JS errors.

Comment: apparently "traditional: true" was needed because of a bug. Thanks for this, I'm bookmarking this answer even if it doesn't solve my problem. I'll try it now.

Comment: event.preventDefault() didn't work in FF or IE. return false works in all browsers. So the JS broke by that line except from in Chrome where the browser accepted the line.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem where "JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet" worked great on chrome, but fails on IE. i tried many formats, but below is the only one worked for IE.

```
return Json(additionalData, "text/html")
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this when using an older version of jQuery.Validate, something to do with a bug in there setting the incorrect dataType.

Make sure you are using the latest version of jQuery.validate

Comment: How do I check that? I use the latest versions of jQuery. I need to have the attribute "traditional: true" since ASP.NET doesn't recognize the response otherwise. Don't know if that matters though.

Answer (score 0):

> return Json(alert, "text/plain");

Usually `Json(alert)` should be enough. Can you try with `application/json; charset=utf-8` as a content type?

Comment: I tried what you suggested before but FF and IE prompts to download the response instead.